# POST JSON to Jersey Service

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to post some json data to REST web service implemented with Jersey framework. I am not using JAXB or jquery but only javascript.
I verified that formed json is correct but in spite of setting content type "application/json", on server it is received as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayFormValues()
    {
        var str = {};
        var elem = document.getElementById('frmMain').elements;

        //alert(elem.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < elem.length-1; i++)
        {
            str[elem[i].name] = elem[i].value;

        }
        document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = str;

        var json = JSON.stringify(str);

        // construct an HTTP request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(document.getElementById('frmMain').method,
                document.getElementById('frmMain').action);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",json.length);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');


        //alert(json);
        // send the collected data as JSON
        xhr.send(json);


        xhr.onloadend = function() {
            // done
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" action="/JerseyTest/rest/postUser"
        method="post">

        <input name="firstName" value="harry" /> <input name="lastName"
            value="tester" /> <input name="toEmail" value="testtest@test.com" />
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Test"
            onclick="DisplayFormValues();" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <div id="lblValues"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On the server side:

```
package com.example.jersey.test;


import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/postUser")
public class JsonTest {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String pingPong(String json) {

        return "Answer is "+ json;
    }
}
```

I am new to web development and not sure on what I am missing in above code.

Comment: This is off the hip but have you tried capitalize the 't' in 'Content-Type'?

Comment: It was in caps only but after checking the request header was trying with small "t". Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question for those who may visit this later. The code above is correct and works well except the fact that the url is been hit twice. First time, for submit button's default action and then as per our script by XMLHttpRequest.
This I came to know after I checked the headers in Httpfox which showed error as **NS_BINDING_ABORTED**.
After changing the input type to button from submit, all is working fine.